Movie where woman presume that no one left for her because everyone is dead
This is a Sci-Fi apocalyptic movie or TV movie from the 80s I believe. I saw it when I was a kid so don't remember a lot of details.
The last scene was three people (two females and a male) and one female was complaining that there was no one left for her because everyone is dead. And then out of nowhere a guy in a convertible drives up and picks her up. It seemed like it was in New York or a city scene with tall buildings. 
During the movie there was one scene where they go into a department store to find clothes.
It was definitely not a main stream movie, no aliens or monsters, there were scientists that were either doing experiments or trying to figure out what killed everyone. 

Night of the Comet, perhaps? I don't remember it that well, myself, but it does feature two women and one man early on. And there's a clothing montage, but that was so common in the '80s as to be wholly unremarkable. 
The last scene features a lament about "being a nun":



And a guy pulls up in convertible at about 2:50, saving our heroine from a lifetime of celibacy.

Great pull! I remembered that scene from that movie too, but you got here before me. Upvote! :)

I know ops asking for this awesome movie, but there are monsters here, mutants.

Yeah, technically. =P I mean, it's all kind of fuzzy, but this wasn't exactly rigorous science-fiction. It's also occurred to me that the OP has mixed up two films, but this closing scene matches pretty close. Upbeat '80s apocalypse ending FTW!

Thanks so much @moviegique I can't believe I got an answer so fast. Your memory is much better than mine. I had that one scene stuck in my head for years. Can't wait to rewatch this!

@Laurie If this is the correct answer, don't forget to approve it (by clicking on the check mark next to it).
